# Button shows multiple times on safari

Tags: css, sass

I have a button inside a container which works as it should in modern browsers (and even IE11) but for some reason is repeated and is nestled in a scrollable callout top of it (the button is NOT nestled in the callout in code at all).

Here is my code:

```
.buttonContainer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 319px;
   height: 62px;
   background-color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #d2d2d2;

}


.button {

    position: fixed;
    left: 39%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);

   .color {
       background-color: #ff0033;
       color: #ffffff;
       display: inline-block;
       height: 26px;
       width: 64px;
       margin-top:10%;
       padding: 8px 16px;
       font-size: 14px;
       cursor: pointer;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
       line-height: 28px;
   }
}
```

Above button will be repeated multiple times in a scrollable callout container **above** of it. In code, the button is not nestled in anything at all. Only button inside its button container.

Comment: You'll probably want to show the relevant HTML as well. Simply adding these classes to a blank document (ex. `<button class="button">`...) and you get the same behavior on all modern browsers.

Comment: also, safari or safari iOS?